# Can't set proxy to CFStream on kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy parameter

Tags: ios, proxy, core-foundation, cfnetwork

I have a question about configuring CF streams to use system specified proxy. Even this simple example with manually configured dictionary won't work and **isSet** field will be set to **false**.
What set of options is expected from developer to be able to apply dictionary to *kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy* parameter?

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, CFSTR("apple.com"), 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
NSDictionary *proxySettings = @{(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost:@"10.0.1.2", (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort:@(8888)};
Boolean isSet = CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy, (__bridge CFTypeRef)proxySettings);
```

I really will appreciate any help, because I struggle with this issue for few months and can't find response.

Best Regards,
Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All was because of usage of plain streams based on socket connection instead of HTTP read stream which is created with `CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest` (I don't know why Apple doesn't have some information along with property name description)

Answer (score 0):

Following code is about `ASIHttpRequest` how to handle proxy settings. If proxy type is socket, you should use `kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy`. Just a supplement for your answer.

```
if ([self proxyHost] && [self proxyPort]) {
    NSString *hostKey;
    NSString *portKey;

    if (![self proxyType]) {
        [self setProxyType:(NSString *)kCFProxyTypeHTTP];
    }

    if ([[self proxyType] isEqualToString:(NSString *)kCFProxyTypeSOCKS]) {
        hostKey = (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxyHost;
        portKey = (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxyPort;
    } else {
        hostKey = (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost;
        portKey = (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort;
        if ([[[[self url] scheme] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
            hostKey = (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost;
            portKey = (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort;
        }
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *proxyToUse = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[self proxyHost],hostKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt:[self proxyPort]],portKey,nil];

    if ([[self proxyType] isEqualToString:(NSString *)kCFProxyTypeSOCKS]) {
        CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream], kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy, proxyToUse);
    } else {
        CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream], kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy, proxyToUse);
    }
```